# Assigning a value to each case in Python?

Tags: python

I'm looking to assign a value to each case in Python. I can carry this out in R, but I don't know how to replicate it in Python.

R Code:

```
data_2017_18 <- data_2017_18 %>%
  mutate(total_inc2 = 45021350)
```

Python attempt:

```
data_2017_18.totalinc2 = 45021350
data_2017_18.totalinc2.value_counts()
```

I am getting an attribute error when I run the count:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Edit:

The aim is to create a new variable on the dataframe that looks like this:

data_2017_18.head()

```
 age sex totalinc2
 0 25  1    45021350  
 1 40  2    45021350
 2 58  1    45021350
 3 39  2    45021350
 4 29  1    45021350
```

Comment: For those of use that don't use R, it's not clear what you are trying to do. What exactly is `data_2017_18`? What do you expect `value_counts` to do?

Comment: what does to assign a value to each case mean?

Comment: When you say "assign a value to each case", how does your code model "cases"? What even is `data_2017_18` before this code?

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you usually use `.where` or `numpy.where`. For both, the first argument is the condition in form of a boolean `np.array`/`pd.Series`. `Numpy.where` allows you to have an `else` case, which is used when the boolean array has entries with `False`.

```
In[1]: df
Out[2]:   colA     colB
       0    1        2
       1    3        4
```

### .where

```
In[1]: df['colA_modified'] = df['colA'].where(df['colA'] == 1, 100)
In[2]: df
    colA    colB    colA_modified
0   1        2         1
1   3        4        100
```

### np.where

```
In[1]: import numpy as np
In[2]: df['colA_modified'] = np.where(df['colA'] == 1, 100, df['colA'])
In[3]: df
    colA    colB    colA_modified
0   1        2         1
1   3        4        100
```

Comment: Thanks, so in the case above it would look like:

Comment: import numpy as np

Comment: data_2017_18['totalinc2'] = np.where(data_2017_18['totalinc'] == 45021350, df['totalinc'])